# Are TF2 taunt bundles clean or dirty?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I would like to know if I buy a taunt bundle, will they come clean (craftable) or dirty (uncraftable) condition?

Comment: I can't say for certain but they're likely to be "dirty". I still think it's insane, though, that anybody cares about "cleanliness" given that, well, *you can't craft taunts anyway.*

Answer (score 3):

All taunts purchased from the store are uncraftable ("dirty"). This can be seen by hovering over the taunt in the store.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you **buy from the store**, they will come **dirty**. Meaning, uncraftable.

If you **unboxed one**, they will come **clean**. Meaning, craftable. Not sure why'd you bother crafting though.

Comment: @AustinMohr The proof is that Taunts are NOT cosmetic items. Rather, they are action items, and action items are always uncraftable when purchased from the store.

Comment: Take a look at this for futher proof: http://www.tf2outpost.com/search/211543753